# How to insert image blob into mysql table in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript

This code below is for signing up.

And I need to insert a profile image blob into mysql DB

So, I made a Buffer instance using Buffer class and try to insert it into the DB, but it failed.

What did I do wrong?

How can I do insert a profile image blob into mysql table?

Any helps would be appreciated.

```
user.post("/SignUp", (req: Request, res: Response) => {

  let fileObj;
  let fileObjStr: string = "NULL";

  if (req.files.length !== 0) {
    fileObj = req.files[0];
    const orgFileName = fileObj.originalname,
      filesize = fileObj.size;

    if (filesize > 1024 * 1000 * 16) {
      console.log("File Size Over 16MB");
      res.json({ FILE_SIZE_OVER: true });
      return;
    }

    fs.open(fileObj.path, "r", function(status, fd) {
      if (status) {
        console.log(status.message);
        return;
      }

      var buffer = new Buffer(filesize);

      fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, filesize, 0, function(err, num) {
        fileObjStr = "'" + buffer + "'";
      });
    });
  }

  sql.connect(userDBConfig,
    (async (con: any) => {
      try {
        const signUpQuery = `
          insert into usersinfotbl (
            ID,
            PW,
            ProfileImage
            ) values(
            '${req.body.ID}',
            '${req.body.PW}',
            ${fileObjStr}
          )
        `;

        await con.query(signUpQuery);
        res.json({ SUCCESS: true });

      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })
  )();
});
```

```
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�W���p}�>o<��%y�\u0001��K���}�M�u߅(�:�˟�uXc�' at line 18",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: '\n' +
    '          insert into usersinfotbl (\n' +
    '            ID,\n' +
    '            PW,\n' +
    '            ProfileImage,\n' +
    '            ) values(\n' +
    "            'someID',\n" +
    "            '1234',\n" +
    "            '�PNG\r\n" +
    '\u001a\n' +
    '\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u00020\u0000\u0000\u0001�\b\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000/�\u001f�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004gAMA\u0000\u0000��\u000b�a\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0000 cHRM\u0000\u0000z&\u0000\u0000��\u0000\u0000�\u0000\u0000\u0000��\u0000\u0000u0\u0000\u0000�`\u0000\u0000:�\u0000\u0000\u0017p��Q<\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0006bKGD\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�C�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0007tIME\u0007�\u0001\u0007\u0017\f\u0010T�8\u0018\u0000\u0000�\u0000IDATx���k�e�v\u0015������1�{�j�c���1�\u0001��}\u0013\u00120"W�\u0015�\u001c\u0011�$ҽ �H(\u000fE�(O���,�\u0010�\u0002B��(R\u0012!�n\u0012�D<\u0014�\u001f�\\\
```

Comment: Yeah, using string interpolation to include binary data in an sql statement is always prone to errors. This is where prepared statements would come handy.

Comment: Note that if the images are of any sort of size (say, over 100k) then it's extremely unusual to want to store them in the db.